# Text Watcher for the MaterialDatePicker manual input

Tags: android, material-design, materialdatepicker

I'm supporting a project using Material version 2. I've integrated the MaterialDatePicker, and there's an option to set the date using a keyboard. The issue I'm facing is that the user has to manually input the date divider '/' every time. This seems unnecessary, and I've been trying to find an option to automatically set the divider after entering 2 symbols. It appears that the developers didn't provide such API. I attempted to use a text watcher, but I couldn't access the dialog's view. Is there any way to achieve this without migrating to Material 3?

### [image]

[image]